# SQL Missing Right Parenthesis in nested PL/SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone help me out.  I'm trying to take the date from one table and insert that into another, then base off the date if it's a weekend or weekday insert that string too. I've been able to do it separately so trying to do it in one swoop I've combined my expressions and now I get the notorious  "missing right parenthesis.

Here's my block:

```
INSERT INTO time (sale_day, date_type) 
  SELECT sd, dt 
    FROM (
     SELECT sale_date AS sd,(
        case
          when dy IS null or dy='' then 'Date Missing'
          when dy='SAT' then 'Weekend'
          when dy='SUN' then 'Weekend'
          else 'Weekday' END) as date_type
            FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR((sale_date), 'DY') AS dy FROM sales) AS dt
      FROM sales
    );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the braces before case and after end. Not needed there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is far too complicated. There is no need for nesting three levels of select.

```
INSERT INTO time (sale_day, date_type) 
SELECT sale_date AS sd,
       case 
         when sale_date IS null then 'Date Missing'
         when TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'DY') in ('SAT', 'SUN') then 'Weekend'
         else 'Weekday' 
       END as date_type
FROM sales;
```

---

Unrelated, but: why are you copying that data into a new table? The query is extremely simple, and it would be more efficient if you just created a view for that information:

```
create or replace view time
as
SELECT sale_date AS sd,
       case 
         when sale_date IS null then 'Date Missing'
         when TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'DY') in ('SAT', 'SUN') then 'Weekend'
         else 'Weekday' 
       END as date_type
FROM sales;
```

That way the information in `time` is always up-to-date without the need to copy data around.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It's just a requirement for for a class I'm taking. Trying to help us understand Data Warehouses/Schemas.

I tried the first block you provided and I'm getting "missing expression".

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for the block. Small error but I got it to work. There was an extra comma at the end of Line 7 and the column should be sale_date instead of date_type.  But thanks it still helped me out greatly.